# How to use different namespaces based on different values in C++?

Tags: c++, string, namespaces

For example, I have 1000 different namespace, they define like follow:

```
namespace FirstScope {
 static const char* arrayTest[2] = {"from a1","from a 2"};
}
namespace SecondScope {
 static const char* arrayTest[12] = {"from b1","from b 2".....};
}
....... etc
```

Each of them has one array which contains strings. These arrays have same name: `arrayTest`
I have a function, it defines like(pesudo code):

```
void function1(string stringValue)
{
  return stringValueScope::arrayTest[0];

}
```

Since I have 1000 different namespaces, I always need to return like

```
StringValueScope::arrayTest[0];
```

The string which is passed to the function1 is definitely the start string of the namespace's name. For example, if the `stringValue` is `test`, we need to return `testScope::arrayTest[0]`. If we call function1 like `function1("First")`, it will return `FirstScope::arrayTest[0]`
Is there any mechanism/method in C++ that can implement that?

Comment: _"I have 1000 different namespace"_ - Well that in itself is a huge problem.

Comment: Sounds like a classic XY problem.

Comment: ^- As in, a terrible abuse of namespaces. I suspect your are auto-generating something, so just generate a map...

Comment: This is not what namespaces are for. If you describe more of your problem maybe someone can suggest an appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. C++ does not have much in the way of things that resemble reflection.

You'll have to find a fundamentally different way to do this. For example, some possibilities (among many):

- If your array data is generated by another program, you could also generate some massive `if...else` to return the correct array (not a great solution but could work in a pinch).
- If your array data is known at compile time, rather than storing everything as arrays in different namespaces, store the data for each in a text file, then use the passed in string to generate the filename and load the data (be sure to sanitize input strings first to avoid security issues, of course). The bonus side-effect of this is you don't have to recompile your binaries if your data changes (on the other hand, it's no longer self-contained, but not sure what your scenario is).
- Register all the arrays in a `map<string,const char **>` ahead of time and do the lookups in there, if your code is generated you should be able to set this up without issue.
- If none of the above work you just have to suck it up and populate a `map` or construct a big `if` manually. The `map` option could be made a bit more flexible using a basic factory-style approach, perhaps. I suppose if there's way too much data to handle this manually you could write a script or something to parse your current source and generate said map/etc. from it, and run it as part of the build process.

Some of those options may be more appropriate than others. You may be able to think of other options as well. But there is no way to do this with namespace or class or variable names alone.

If it inspires you to think of other options: Keep in mind that if the data *is* generated by another program you don't necessarily need to use namespaces, there are infinite other ways to organize the data.